# How to obtain both values from a voltage attenuator?

Tags: voltage-divider, attenuator

Design a resistive voltage attenuator whose input resistance be 1 MΩ (R1,R2) and able to divide by 5 the amplitude of a DC voltage when the output of the attenuator is connected to a circuit with 1 MΩ input resistance (\$R_i\$.)

The result is:

- R1=800kΩ
- R2=250kΩ

My question is how do I get those resistor values out a voltage attenuation equation?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Is this homework?

Comment: no, is just an example I have come across, and after doing my maths my results are totally different. I was wondering if I was doing something wrong, that's all...

Comment: You need to know how to work out the value of parallel resistors. Can you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the total resistance of the divider R1 + R2 ||Ri = 1M\$\Omega\$, thus  R2 || 1M\$\Omega\$ = 200K\$\Omega\$ for 0.2 division, so

R1 = 1M\$\Omega\$ - 200K\$\Omega\$ = 800K\$\Omega\$.

R2||1M\$\Omega\$ = 200K\$\Omega\$ so

1/R2 = (1/200K\$\Omega\$) - (1/1M\$\Omega\$) => R2 = 250K\$\Omega\$